# SpringMVC , OData and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, odata

I am in starting phase of **OData** that i want to use with **Spring MVC** and **MongoDB** .
kindly, explain that is it proper to use **OData** with **MonogoDB** and **Spring MVC** and if it is than kindly given a **simple example** of that.